# ActionBar does not appear when using Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` and in my main activity that extends `AppCompatActivity` I get an ActionBar exactly as expected. In another activity that also extends `AppCompatActivity` I get these errors when the activity loads:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{activity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
        at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2366)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
        at com.nick.simplequiz.TabletGallery.onCreate(TabletGallery.java:53)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2366)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
```

the error is caused by these lines:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff01579b));
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

And without those lines causing the errors the activity will run and an actionbar is not visible. Why is the action bar not visible when using this theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getSupportActionBar()` to get the ActionBar in your `AppCompatActivity`:

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff01579b));
bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```